# Can you Use more than one domain via Multisite in Wordpress for the top level domain

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Was hoping that someone might be able to tell me something or at least point me in the right direction.

I am currently running Wordpress Multi Site combined with Woocommerce, WPUltimo & WP Frontend Admin to accomplish an E-Commerce based WaaS system. However while the system is currently working just fine there is a design tweak I would love to accomplish.

What I am effectively seeking to do and wanted to know if it is possible would be
to do what Shopify has done where their primary site is located at [www.shopify.com](http://www.shopify.com) but when a user registers to the platform their storefront is created using storename.myshopify.com

What I would like to know is if it is possible to accomplish the same thing via wordpress multisite with the above referenced plugins and domain mapping.

My ideal outcome would be

Main site mysite.com

Subsites get created based on the customers selection during checkout via a drop down list of TLD's we have available and the customer gets to pick the tld that they want their subdomain to be part of.  https://theirsitename.{insert chosen tld.com}

I know that mapping can be done for the subsites to their own domain name where subdomain.primarydomain.tld may be the primary domain and [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) would become an alias of subdomain.primarydomain.tld

But what i am asking is if there is a way to map the main domain of the multisite network to another domain so [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) becomes a alias of [www.primarydomain.com](http://www.primarydomain.com) and have subsites be created using the alised domain rather than the actual domain name.